# R: caret package and functional data

Tags: r, r-caret

My question is simple. Does the caret package deal with functional data, or am I better suited with other packages?

Comment: There is the package 'tidyfun' for handling funtional data. But also depends a little bit on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do kNN classification with functional data. I already know some packages to do this with, I was just wandering if it is possible to do it with caret.

Comment: As far as I know it isn't directly possible in caret.